# apache rewriting url doesn't work(using godaddy hosting)

Tags: apache, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, godaddy

I'm using a framework to create my website(codeigniter) by default the urls are like this:`mysite.com/index.php?/etc/etc/etc`.
And I'm trying to remove the `index.php?`, I tried to remove it by doing this(didn't work):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L]
```

Note:
it's working on my localhost(when putting my website's files in the root directiory).

So, Is this issue associated with me or the hosting company(Go Daddy)?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue a few weeks ago.  Even with mods to my `.htaccess` file, I was never able to accomplish the `rewrite` with a site being hosted on GoDaddy.  They have a 'manual' way of doing it through their Control Panel which ended up working for me.

http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/5120/redirect-urls-with-your-hosting-account

As far as I'm concerned, it got the job done, but it certainly was backwards....

Comment: The tool is used to redirect pages, and that's not what I exactly need, I need to clean my links, like this: `mywebsite.com/index.php?/site` to `mywebsite.com/site`

Answer (score 1):

Is your `.htaccess` file working at all? If no are you on a Linux or Windows server at GoDaddy? If Windows here is an article on [switching to Linux](http://support.godaddy.com/groups/web-hosting/forum/topic/switch-from-windows-to-linux-server-and-index-php) which is very easy

Comment: I think it is working, because I get 404 when trying to access my website(which means it did effect my website).And yeah, I'm using Linux already.